# How to connect SSRS into ReportViewer 2010 at Runtime?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have my codes as bellow and it shows me empty page after compiling:

```
ReportViewerControl = new ReportViewer();
            ShowZoomControl="false"
            ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportServerUri);
            ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.ReportPath = Model.Report.ReportPath;
            ReportViewerControl.Visible = true;
            ReportViewerControl.ShowReportBody = true;
            ReportViewerControl.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            ReportViewerControl.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ReportViewerControl.ShowZoomControl = false;
            ReportViewerControl.ShowBackButton = false;
            ReportViewerControl.InteractivityPostBackMode = InteractivityPostBackMode.AlwaysAsynchronous;
            ReportViewerControl.Height = 780;
            ReportViewerControl.Width = 800;

            IList<ReportParameter> FishSpeciesParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
            ReportParameter SPStatus = new ReportParameter();
            SPStatus.Name = "SPStatus";
            if (Model.Report.ID == 8)
                SPStatus.Values.Add("T,E,C");
            ReportParameter FishCode = new ReportParameter();
            FishCode.Name = "FishCode";
            FishCode.Values.Add("11");
            FishSpeciesParameters.Add(SPStatus);
            FishSpeciesParameters.Add(FishCode);

            ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.SetParameters(FishSpeciesParameters);

            ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Any Ideas to view SSRS Report into ReportViewer on Fly?

Answer (score 0):

maily you just need to set ServerReport.ReportServerUrl to something like this:

`"http://localhost:8080/ReportServer"`

and the ReportPath to

```
reportFolder + "/" + reportName;
```